# Mac freezes when logging in as >console [logging in to terminal directly without launching the GUI]

Tags: macos, terminal, login, console

When I try console login, my Mac freezes. Nothing happens visually: no switch to a black window, no spinning loading indicator in the ‘Password’ field; nothing. The only thing I can still do is press the [Power] button until the Mac force shuts down.

I already reinstalled the OS tons, and the machine ever did this as far as I know. I tried to do it before configuring the OS, after etc; nothing worked so far.

[image: Login settings]
[image: Mac froze]

I found on the Internet that other people had that problem, but the posts are old and no one ever answered to help.

What can I do? Thanks.

**Note:** That Mac went under OS X Yosemite, but I downgraded since. I can't recall if I tried to login into console before first installing OS X Yosemite. I hope it's not due to this, because I won't update this working machine no more.

**Hardware Overview:**

- Model Name: MacBook Pro [Retina, 15in, late 2013]
- Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,3
- Boot ROM Version: MBP112.0138.B16
- SMC Version (system): 2.19f12

**System Software Overview:**

- System Version: OS X 10.9.5 (13F1808)
- Kernel Version: Darwin 13.4.0
- Boot Mode: Normal
- Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled

Comment: Sometimes FileVault causes this problem. If you have enabled it please try to log in with disabled FileVault. For me it looks like a kernel extension during startup. Boot into Recovery (CMD + R) or Safe boot (press Shift-key during start up) and open the Terminal. Type: pkgutil --pkgs | grep -v com.apple. You get a list of third party kernel extensions (if you have). Try do disable or temporary remove it.

Comment: @dante12 Interesting. FileVault has never been enabled on that Mac, but I didn't think about kernel extensions… I first thought it was due to the downgrade from OS X Yosemite, since I guess there could've been an error with a kernel update. I'll try that and tell you back.

Comment: @dante12 In Recovery's terminal, `pkgutil --pkgs | grep -v com.apple` returns nothing. :/ The same command in Safe boot, however, returns quite a list. I try to disable 'em all, and give you feedback right after.

Comment: @dante12 OK matey, I listed third-party kexts with your command in Safe boot mode. Most of those shown weren't unloadable, so I ran the exact same command, replacing `pkgutil --pkgs` with `kextstat`, which only shown one kext (from BlackBerry). I disabled that one BlackBerry's kext with `sudo kextunload -b { kext identifier }`, logged out and tried to login as >console  [still in Safe boot mode], which worked. A reboot later, console login still freezes the Mac, and I have no clue about what keeps doing this. :/

Comment: When the OS is booted normally, if I unload all third-party kexts, logout then login as `>console`, the screen now goes white-gray, but nothing else occurs and I can't do anything else than force shut the Mac down. I tried to login then logout and login as `>console` without unloading kexts, and it does the same. I don't know what else changes in Safe boot mode, but it is the only way that I know I can login as `>console` for now.

Comment: 1. unplug the power for several seconds.and plug it back in. 2. shut down your mac and remove and reinsert the battery (if removable). 3, Restart your mac. 4. During start up hold down the keys CMD + Option + P + R, hold down the keys until you hear the second sound. 5. Restart and test. If not works doing the next steps: Boot into recovery (CMD + R) during startup and repair the system drive with disk utility. 6, At last option check for Hardware issues. Restart your mac and hold the D - Key down, This will boot into diagnostic enviroment and check for any problems.

Comment: @dante12 I didn't see your comment, thank you. I was reinstalling OS X Mavericks from a USB flash drive (thanks to `createinstallmedia`), reset PRAM and SNC at installation reboot and console login finally worked [while it's strange, I already did that before and it didn't work, I don't know why]. I still haven't run my configuration script, I'll comment a thing or two in it before doing so. Right now, I reinstall all my software then I'll give it one more try. If it does not work, it's likely that some software does this. Otherwise, my configuration script might be the cause.

Comment: Okay, I just reinstalled everything, logged out and console logged in; no software I use does this. Since UNIX stuff does not break like that, I say there are high chances that my script sets something wrong.

Comment: Oh for Christ's sake, I may have found the cause of this. I had a feeling it could be due to Retina; I don't know why, I felt like it. I set the Retina on 'More space', logged out and console logged in. The screen did not refresh to a black console like it does usually; I got some black lines with white characters, hexadecimal addresses, which indicated 'Kernel panic'. Then the screen went gray, with the kernel panic message and icon. Then the Mac restarted. I retried when it came back, and it froze. I force shut down the Mac, put the Retina on 'Best (Retina)' back, and will post what happens.

Comment: Okay, I logged in again, put the Retina back to its original settings, logged out and console logged back in. A big spinning cursor appeared for seconds, then the screen refreshed to the console. For Christ's sake, this is unbelievable. I don't know why or how it came to my mind, though. [I think I made a link to the facts that the resolution in the console clearly changes, and that Safe boot mode disables Retina prefs, displaying on 'Best (Retina)'. Quite the bull's-eye wild guess whatsoever. I wonder what the Retina has to do in this.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too long; won't read:** Set the Retina resolution as 'Best (Retina)' or below to fix console login crashing and freezing issue.

On my Retina 15in late 2013 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks, the Retina causes console login to crash [if you changed Retina settings to above 'Best (Retina)', logout then console log back in] or crash with a kernel panic [if you changed Retina settings above 'Best (Retina)', reboot then console login].

This explains why Safe mode is unaffected by that bug, as Retina settings are reverted back to original ones.

[image: System preferences: Display: Resolution: Scaled: More Space]

Unless a fix rolls out, the best to do to fix that problem is to set Retina preferences as 'Best (Retina)' maximum; below, console login will work flawlessly and above, console login will crash or freeze [following if you logged out the console logged back in or reboot the machine, respectively].

Note that if you were in any setting above 'Best (Retina)', the Mac must be reboot to stop the console login from crashing or freezing.

**Too long; didn't read:** Set the Retina resolution as 'Best (Retina)' or below to fix console login crashing and freezing issue.